# Custom membership with OWIN

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I am having problem understanding how to set current/custom principal on Thread/HttpRequest Context when using OWIN middleware. Feels like that happens under the hood but i need to have custom principal just like i would have it in Global.asax on authenticate request when using forms autnehtication.

Any ideas where and how to do that?

[EDIT]

I will try to put in a bit more details.
So, when using FormsAuthentication, in Accounts/Login controller i check users credentals and if they are valid i create FormsAuthenticationTicket with UserData in it set and send all of it as a cookie. When user sends request to the App next time i read the cookie in Global.asax Application_PostAuthenticateRequest, decrypt it and based on the information in UserData i create an istance of my CustomPrincipal (which inherits from GenericPrincipal) an set Thread.Principal and HttpContext.Principal to that GenericPrincipal.

Now i am interested in doing the same thing with OWIN Bearer token authentication but i just can't find any reference/examples.

Hope its a bit more clear now.

Comment: How are you authenticating the user?

Comment: Not sure what do you mean by 'how' but i guess answer is through usual OWIN Bearer token.